# 0x transactions failing due to out of gas for swaps consistently

Tags: 0x

My transactions to swap keep running out of gas and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm generating a quote like below (which is actually a snippet from a 0x repository)

const response = await fetch(
`${ZRX_API_URL}/quote?sellToken=${tokenAddressSell}&buyToken=${tokenAddressBuy}&sellAmount=${tokenUnitAmount}${takerAddressString}${skipValidationString}${buyTokenPercentage}`,
);```

And then feeding this quote to the transaction

```
txHash = await web3Wrapper.sendTransactionAsync({...swapQuote, from: accountAddress} as Required<SwapQuoteResponse>);
```

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x58dcfbd6c9e2525b7c578b073284b28acf511fc73e79edf1dc29524312a0fb5a
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4836398a647e509e53afaa1a23c725329f26510fd327fa917587f7c363e339a7
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9627a2c511266b19014c4abf63399d16cd446975b6d18437c226fe3375b9e28e

Looks like the gas limit is always 280K across all three transactions

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to determine from the code snippet you posted but in 99% of the cases when the gas limit is too low the `takerAddress` is not correctly passed to 0x API when requesting the quote.

Please verify that you are correctly passing `takerAddress=0x....` when requesting the quote, and that the address is the same as the one sending the transaction.

If it still doesn't work, please post the full quote request url with all params.

Comment: Also `skipValidationString` should be `false` if you want an accurate estimate